# Don't copy files into project for twitter-bootstrap-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-rails

Rails 4.2.4
Ruby 2.1.2

I am trying to use [twitter-bootstrap-rails](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails).
I would like to use it by the same way I am using [jquery-rails](https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails)

**assets/applications.js**

```
//= require jquery
```

In this case I don't need to copy any jquery.js or jquery.css files to my project because Rails fetches it for me form gem.

**The different situation is with twitter-bootstrap-rails.**

In the guide

> The Twitter Bootstrap Rails gem can provide the Bootstrap stylesheets
>   in two ways.
>
> The plain CSS way is how Bootstrap is provided on the official
>   website.
>
> The Less way provides more customization options, like changing theme
>   colors, and provides useful Less mixins for your code, but requires
>   the Less gem and the Ruby Racer Javascript runtime (not available on
>   Microsoft Windows).

Seems the first way is more suitable for me.  But in this case I should use the generator `rails generate bootstrap:install static` before to use any twitter-bootstrap .js or .css files. The generator fetches the files into assets folder of my project.

So I am looking for a way how to use `twitter-bootstrap-rails` .js and .css files in my project without copying them into my project folder. I just would like to add `twitter-bootstrap-rails` files just putting for instance line `//= require bootstrap` into `application.js`.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: With the generator you shouldn't need to modify your asset manifest (`application.css` and `application.js`) files.

Comment: But my manifest file `application.css` complains that couldn't find bootstrap file unless I generate it by `rails g`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `twitter-bootstap-rails`, use [`bootstrap-sass`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass).
In your `application.js`, add the following:

```
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
```

change `application.css` to `application.scss` and add:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

and you're good to go. Oh. Just please don't forget to restart your server.

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question.

Comment: Noted, but that's what comments are for, not answers.